# how do you fix Element Not Interactable Exception: python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I'm trying to code a bot for [www.kith.com](http://www.kith.com) I just finished the card number now I'm on the name on the card. I found the xpath but it says element not interactable.

code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\webdrivers\Chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://kith.com/products/kith-women-x-coca-cola-cropped-camp-collar-ivory-multi')
     
    #size
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-value="M"]').click()
    
    #ATC
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn product-form__add-to-cart"]').click()
time.sleep(6)
    
    #checkout
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn ajaxcart__checkout"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
    
    #email
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Email"]').send_keys('example@gmail.com')
    
    #first
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="First name"]').send_keys('first')
    
    #last
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Last name"]').send_keys('last')
    
    #address
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Address"]').send_keys('address')
    
    #city
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="City"]').send_keys('city')
    
    #zip
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="ZIP code"]').send_keys('99999')
    
    #phone number
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Phone"]').send_keys('9999999999' + u'\ue007')
time.sleep(5)

    #continue to payment
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
time.sleep(8)
    
   #payment page 
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("card-fields-iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_id("number").send_keys('1234')
driver.find_element_by_id("number").send_keys('1234')
driver.find_element_by_id("number").send_keys('1234')
driver.find_element_by_id("number").send_keys('1234')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="name"]').send_keys("jake d")
```

error occurs in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with 4 `iframes`. For example, for the `Name on card` you can use :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'Name on card')]"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-current-field]").send_keys('1234')
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

The last line is used to switch back to the main content. The XPath to select the `input` element is always the same for the 4 iframes.

Side note : You should use `Selenium EC` (expected conditions) instead of `time.sleep`. To locate the 4 iframes and send your keystrokes, you can use the following.

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@title,'Card number')]"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-current-field]"))).send_keys('1234')
driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@title,'Name on card')]"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-current-field]"))).send_keys('john')
driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@title,'Expiration date')]"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-current-field]"))).send_keys('1123')
driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@title,'Security code')]"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-current-field]"))).send_keys('1234')
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I appreciate you

Comment: I got an error that I've never gotten before... WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@title,'Card number')]"))

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Try to add an extra `()` in the expressions. `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@title,'Card number')]")))`

Comment: i hate to keep asking questions however the extra ) got rid of the __init__ error now i get “raise timeout exception”

Comment: Increase the waiting time of the WebDriver (`driver.20`) to circumvent this type of issue.